# Error in Loading Service Configuration

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a `CampusCalendarBundle` extension. After I added the `DependencyInjection` folder to load config files. I have this error. I don't think `system_configuration.yml` is been loaded.

```
[RuntimeException]
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]                                                                                                            

The system configuration variable "oro_calendar.calendar_colors" is not   
defined. Please make sure that it is either added to bundle 
configuration settings or marked as "ui_only" in config.
```

[image]

```
<?php

namespace CampusCRM\CampusCalendarBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class CampusCalendarExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter(
            'oro_calendar.enabled_system_calendar',
            $config['enabled_system_calendar']
        );

        $container->prependExtensionConfig($this->getAlias(), array_intersect_key($config, array_flip(['settings'])));

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        $loader->load('form.yml');
    }
}
```

Here is extension Bundle.

```
<?php

// src/CampusCRM/CampusCalendarBundle/CampusCalendarBundle.php
namespace CampusCRM\CampusCalendarBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class CampusCalendarBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'OroCalendarBundle';
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the link for that Bundle Extension maybe it would be better for us.

Comment: Respond to your previous questions comments and you might get help!

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what Bundle Extension to provide. `CampusCalendarBundle` extends `OroCalendarBundle`. Do you want to see `OroCalendarBundle`? Here is the link for [OroCalendarBundle](https://github.com/orocrm/OroCalendarBundle)

Comment: Did you require the `system_configuration.yml` in your `app/config/config.yml` file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a solution! I probably accidentally deleted some code in `OroCalendarBundle`. Everything works after I replaced `OroCalendarBundle` with a refresh install.

Thank you everyone for your help~